# REDUX - How to import an API function returning Promise and add it into payload on action creator

Tags: redux

My Redux is rusty to say the least, I am trying to import functions from API which returns a Promise. I want to add this Promise to the payload on action creator, but it complains that `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBetList' of undefined`

Here is my action creator:

```
import { getBetList, getLatestPrices } from '../api/index';
export const GET_BET_LIST = 'GET_BET_LIST';
export const GET_LATEST_PRICES = 'GET_LATEST_PRICES';


export function fetchBetList() {
  const response = this.getBetList();

  return {
    type: GET_BET_LIST,
    payload: response
  }
}

export function fetchLatestPrices() {
  const response = this.getLatestPrices();

  return {
    type: GET_LATEST_PRICES,
    payload: response
  }
}
```

I assumed that Promise received from API will be available on payload, will flow through redux-promise and in the end I get data I need, but it stops with an error that it cannot read getBetList? where did I do a wrong on import here?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getBetList` & `getLatestPrices` directly since you imported it on a top of the file. Remove `this` from the line below will fix your error.

```
const response = this.getBetList();
                 ^^^^
```

And same here

```
const response = this.getLatestPrices();
```

Btw it won't work either you should use async flow for that like so:

```
export function fetchLatestPrices() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    getLatestPrices()
      .then(response => dispatch({type: GET_LATEST_PRICES, payload: response}));

  }
}
```

More information about [`async actions`](https://redux.js.org/advanced/asyncactions)

Comment: Yes, that worked, now have different issue, but this ticket is closed