# Redux - Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions. redux-promise

Tags: redux, redux-promise

Now after resolving the issue here
[REDUX - How to import an API function returning Promise and add it into payload on action creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51575095/redux-how-to-import-an-api-function-returning-promise-and-add-it-into-payload#51575149)

I have the following error:

> Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async
>   actions. ▶ 3 stack frames were collapsed. App.componentWillMount
>   src/component/App.js:18   15 | }   16 |    17 | componentWillMount() {
>
> > 18 |   const data = this.props.fetchBetList();   19 |   this.setState({ items: data })   20 | }   21 |  View compiled ▶ 24
> >     stack frames were collapsed. ./src/index.js src/index.js:31   28 |
> >     29 | const createStoreWithMiddleware =
> >     applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);   30 | 
> >     31 | ReactDOM.render(   32 |      33 |        34 |
> >      View compiled ▶ 6 stack frames were collapsed. This screen
> >     is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes
> >     in production. Open your browser’s developer console to further
> >     inspect this error.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import BetList from './BetList';
import './App.css';
import items from '../data/betItems.json';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchBetList, fetchLatestPrices } from '../actions/index';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      items: []
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const data = this.props.fetchBetList();
    this.setState({ items: data })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Tottenham Hotspur v Manchester City</h1>
        <h2>Correct Score</h2>
        <BetList items={this.state.items} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { fetchBetList, fetchLatestPrices })(App);
```

I tried to obtain resolved Promise and use lifecycle method to update state.items....

Comment: Redux doesn't natively support async action creators. If you want those, use Redux Thunk or similar middleware

Comment: But I use redux-promise, should I use redux-thunk instead?

Comment: You are setting the data right after an async call that fetches it. You need to handle the promise in your reducer. Using redux-promise is fine.